# Buy Omega 3 eggs in bulk?

Tags: eggs

I maintain to a high protein diet and consume a lot of eggs. No, seriously, *a lot* of eggs. I want to make the switch to Omega 3 eggs but I'm not really able to find these in bulk through your average grocery story. Whenever I ask for bulk eggs, they always show me the box of 5-dozen eggs from unknown origin - yuck. Is this something that a restaurant supplier would carry? A local farm? How would I go about finding Omega 3 eggs in bulk?

Comment: Hello Jim Beam, it would really help if you were to divulge your location. I imagine the answers would be different for different parts of the world.

Comment: @Jay Makes sense, thank you. I am in the greater Las Vegas area.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Hit farm markets and organic co-ops to locate local producers. If the ones who are there can't supply you, they usually know a producer who can. If they don't have omega-3- eggs, they may know who does/

Step 2: Do your research. Ask prospective suppliers about their feeds (lots of greens, alfalfa and fish by-products are desirable, as opposed to grains, animal fats and layer pellets) and certifications, if they have such. Also, ask if the producer allows client walkabouts, guided or otherwise; if the producer doesn't, it may be that the chickens are kept in unhealthy conditions or are not being fed what the producer claims.

Step 3: Be loyal and respect your source. If a producer purchases extra stock in order to supply your eggs, support that supplier. If the quality declines, warn the supplier that you will have to change sellers to get the same quality as you used to. If you need to leave and won't be purchasing for a few weeks, let the producer know so that he or she can sell the eggs elsewhere instead of keeping the eggs for too long. Either way, don't just jump ship. In particular, don't jump ship and then try to come back. Things talk their way around, and you might find yourself without any supplier at all.